# Tensorflow equivalent for cv2.addWeighted?

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

Is there a TensorFlow equivalent for `cv2.addWeighted()`? I need this function for image processing on my `tf.dataset` object.

If there isn't, how can I use the OpenCV method with TensorFlow to get the same result?

Here is my code below for reference.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.image import ResizeMethod
import pathlib
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import cv2
from PIL import Image

np.set_printoptions(precision=4)
filepaths = df['filepath'].values
labels = df[[0,2,4]].values


ds_train = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((filepaths, labels))

def read_image(image_file, labels):
    img = tf.io.read_file(image_file)
    img = tf.image.decode_png(img, channels=3, dtype=tf.uint8)

    
    img = tf.image.resize(img, [512, 512], preserve_aspect_ratio=False)
    
    img2 = ...
    
    # Need something equivalent to cv2.addWeighted() to use on img and img2
  
    return img, labels

ds_train = ds_train.map(read_image).batch(32, drop_remainder = True)
```

I apologize in advance if this question has already been answered. I searched everywhere and could not find a way to replicate this.

Comment: Please don't edit "solved" into the title. Instead, click on the gray checkmark to the left of the answer, turning it green. That indicates your question is answered satisfactorily. https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/376604

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I may have found a work-around by using other tensorflow functions.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_addons as tfa
def tensorflow_addWeighted(img1, img2):
     img = img1 * tf.multiply(tf.ones(image1_shape, dtype = tf.uint8), alpha) + img2 * tf.multiply(tf.ones(image2_shape, dtype = tf.uint8), beta) + lambda
     return img
```

This is the same formula in the OpenCV docs, implemented with tensorflow. Alpha, beta, and lambda are the corresponding weight values as you would use them in OpenCV.